# Editing existing keyboard layout

Tags: linux, linux-mint, keyboard-layout, unicode

I'm using the English US keyboard layout, but I often find myself needing to type certain Unicode characters (namely, greek letters often used in Math) and I notice that the US layout has almost no mappings for the Alt Car key. Ideally, I'd want to be able to get the Unicode representation for say, Sigma by pressing Alt Car + S, Epsilon by pressing Alt Car + E, etc.

What's the easiest way of doing this?

Comment: Have you looked into configuring a Compose key?  This works quite nicely as a way to make CapsLock useful.  For example, you can use Compose-a-e to type æ,or Compose-A-E to type Æ, or Compose-e-' to type é.  You can create any sequence you like for any glyph you like in your `.XCompose` configuration file.

Comment: @DopeGhoti I did not know that was a thing. That looks like quite a handy solution to my problem. Does it work across all layouts? Say I'm switching between US English and CA French?

Comment: Also, where is this file located?

Comment: A full guide can be found at https://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/1351 which also shows the system-wide configuration file for Compose key settings (to wit: `/usr/share/X11/locale/<your locale here>/Compose`).  `.XCompose` would exist in your home directory and override the system-wide settings, presumably regardless of locale, which would allow you to carry your custom Compose settings between en-US and fr-CA.